# Изменение размера изображения jQuery?

Tags: jquery, изображения

Всем привет! Такой вопрос, у меня есть изображения, я вывожу их таким образом http://cash-back.kz/index.php/products/cat/komp_yuternaya_tehnika/date можете посмотреть слева эти изображения.

Я вывожу их через цикл, и возникла нужда, выровнить все строчки в одинаковую высоту. Сейчас я все изображения беру и ставлю им width:140px, а высота автоматически. Получается то что когда высота больше ширины то по высоте колонке становится большой как 4 и 5 продукт по ссылке.

Нужно сделать так, наверно через jquery. Если высота больше ширины то изменять в изображении не width, а height. Если ширина больше высоты то так же как и сейчас ставить width.

p.s Изначально изображения на сервер загружается в разных размерах, только при выводе я ставлю width и height.
Подскажите как реализовать? 
Спасибоо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В цикл вставляешь код ниже, в нем делится высота на ширину или наоборот, получаем коэффициент, и уже по коэффициенту смотрим выводить картинку по ширине или по высоте.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'путь к артинки';
img.onload = function()
{
    if((img.height/img.width) > 1.5)
    {
        // выводим картинку
    }
    else
    {
        // выводим картинку
    }
}
```

Comment: можно сделать еще проще выставив свойства css max-height и max-width

Comment: хотя нет, средствами css врятли получится